# Expiration date with template not working

Tags: c#, microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection

I have configured a template with an exploration date:

```
Get-AipServiceTemplateProperty -TemplateId 7a3e9ebd-a14e-4520-ba34-434029030633 -ContentExpirationDate -ContentExpirationOption | Format-List
Key   : ContentExpirationOption
Value : OnDate

Key   : ContentExpirationDate
Value : 12/25/2020 11:56:00 AM
```

And then I set protection to file with this template

```
ProtectionDescriptor protectionDescriptor = new ProtectionDescriptor("7a3e9ebd-a14e-4520-ba34-434029030633");
```

The file successfully encrypted and the permission is set but it looks like the exploration date didn't work. When I open the file Word doesn't show me until when the file is valid.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, as it shows `12/25/2020 11:56:00 AM` for the key `ContentExpirationDate` but you didn't find it work. So please check the the time zone of the expiration date, check if it matches UTC time zone and doesn't match your local time zone.

Comment: the Get-AipServiceTemplateProperty command doesn't allow me to set ContentExpirationDate with a value that passed my local time zone (and before UTC time)